# How do I automatically loop through dynamic ranges to sort by date?

Tags: vba, sorting

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim onecell As Range
Dim twocell As Range
Dim threecell As Range
Dim fourcell As Range
Dim fivecell As Range
Dim sixcell As Range


Dim aCell As Range

Set onecell = Range("B2:G21")
Set twocell = Range("B25:G38")
Set threecell = Range("B42:G55")
Set fourcell = Range("J2:O21")
Set fivecell = Range("J25:O38")
Set sixcell = Range("J42:O55")

Set aCell = Range("B2")
onecell.Sort Key1:=aCell, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
twocell.Sort Key1:=aCell, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
threecell.Sort Key1:=aCell, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
fourcell.Sort Key1:=aCell, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
fivecell.Sort Key1:=aCell, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
sixcell.Sort Key1:=aCell, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

End Sub

This is my worksheet. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkAJv.png

Please disregard the sorting key. I haven't completed that area yet. What I would do is assign it a particular static cell which would work. I'm only asking about the dynamic ranges.

What I want to do is loop through each box and sort the entries in there by ascending date. The code I have so far only does this via a static method by assigning a particular range. The problem I'm concerned with is if the data extends beyond the boxes. In particular, how do I add a row if the data will extend beyond these boxes?

Also, how do I assign the sorting to sort dynamically rather than with static ranges?

Comment: have you looked into named ranges?

Comment: I did look into that. But the problem with that is I don't know how to loop through each box.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the currentRegion property (property of Range). It is the range that is selected in Excel when pressing CTRL+*.

Try it out. Make your sheet in such a way that CTRL+* selects the required data.